# Increment Serial Numbers and calculate - javascript

Tags: javascript

Our company has a client that requires a specific checksum on their bar codes. I've come up with the following which allows the user to enter the distributor part number, our part number and our serial number.  Right now, when you click save, it will calculate correctly for the bar code with the checksum.  NOW, we have added a quantity box so that we can print x number of barcodes with our serial number incrementing by 1.  (i.e. 1st serial number is 000001, next will be 000002 and so on).  What I've been trying to do for the last week is alter this code so the user can input the part numbers and sn, and it will calculate each bar code up to the quantity. 
This is what we would like to have:
[If user enters part numbers, first serial number and quantity then clicks "Save" this should be the result. At present, this can only be achieved by entering each serial number and clicking save](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UTL5.jpg)

*note: while the quantity can be entered, the actual value has not been used in my code...yet

So, to achieve this, I need to find a way to increment the serial numbers without dropping off the leading zeros but maintaining the length of qty.length.
I also need to figure out how to loop each new serial number through with part numbers to get the correct checksum for the bar code. After a week of staring at this, I'm hoping some fresh and experienced eyes can assist.  Here is my code.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Capture Form Fields to CSV</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

function saveValues() {
    var frm = document.form1;
  var str = frm.text1.value + frm.text2.value + frm.text3.value;
  var dpn = frm.text1.value;
  var wpn = frm.text2.value;
  var wsn = frm.text3.value;
  var strArray = str.split(""); 
  var calcArray = strArray;
  var total =0;
  
  
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
strArray[i] = strArray[i].charCodeAt(0); 
  
for (var i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++){
    if (strArray[i] >= 65 && strArray[i] <= 90){
    calcArray[i] = (strArray[i] - 64) * (i+1)
    }
    else if (strArray[i] >=97 && strArray[i] <=122) {
    calcArray[i] = (strArray[i] - 96) * (i+1) 
    }
    else if (strArray[i] >=48 && strArray[i] <=57) {
    calcArray[i] = (strArray[i] - 48) * (i+1)
    }
    else {
    calcArray[i] = 1 * (i+1) 
    }
    }

for (var i in calcArray){
total += calcArray[i];}  
var mod2 = str.length - (2*(Math.floor(str.length/2))); 
var mod10 = (total + mod2) - (10*(Math.floor((total + mod2)/10))) ;
var chk = mod10;
var record = ""
           + dpn + "," + wpn + "," + wsn + "," +dpn + "~" + wpn + "~" + wsn + "~" + chk + "\n";
            
    frm.textarea1.value += record;
    
}

function clearText() {
    document.form1.textarea1.value = "";P
    form1.text1.value = "";
    form1.text2.value = "";
    form1.text3.value = "";
}

function csvSave() {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
        with (a) {
              href='data:text/csv;base64,' + btoa(document.getElementById('textarea1').value);
              download='csvfile.csv';
          }
          document.body.appendChild(a);
          a.click();
          document.body.removeChild(a);
          }

//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Capture Form Fields to CSV</h1>

<form name="form1" >
  <p>
    Distributor Part Number: <input name="text1" type="text" value="GDM1301" /><br />
    Our Part Number: <input name="text2" type="text" value="PCBDM160"/><br />
    Our Serial Number: <input name="text3" type="text" value="000001"/><br />
    Label Quantity: <input name="qty" type="text" value="3"/>    
    
  </p>
  <p>
    <input name="save" type="button" value="Save"
           onclick="saveValues(); return false"/>
    &#0160;
    <input name="clear" type="button" value="Clear"
           onclick="clearText(); return false"/>
    <button onclick="csvSave()">CSV</button>       

  </p>
  <p>
    <i>Click 'Save' to add content</i><br />
    <textarea id="textarea1" cols="80" rows="20"></textarea>         
  </p>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So is the overall problem here how to increment some number in the form of `000001` to `000002` and so on? If so what part of your code are you attempting this?

Comment: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/formatnumber.shtml

Comment: Correct.  For the serial number (var wsn = frm.text3.value) I need to keep the leading zeros.  Right now, those are 11 digit numbers, but in the future it could be fewer digits or more digits.  I need the leading zeros to be added back in based on the length of the inputted serial number. (as a side note, I've never programmed in javascript before...this just got thrown in my lap because the person in Engineering quit...normally, I just handle network security...so I'm in uncharted waters just learning as I go...)

Comment: I was able to break down my code and create this:
  function saveValues() {
    var frm = document.form1;
  var wsn = frm.text3.value;
  var qty = frm.qty.value;
    var numArr = new Array (qty);
    
for (var i = 0; i < qty; i++){
numArr[i] = parseInt(wsn) + i;
}
var record = ""
           + numArr + "\n";
            
    frm.textarea1.value += record;
    
}
 and it yields the correct results except it doesn't have the leading zeros...

Comment: I was hoping to do something along the lines of String.format("%text3.length" , parseInt(wsn) + i)